# How to store 2 variable's value into .csv file as 2 separate columns using JSR223 listener in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, export-to-csv, jsr223, json-extract

I have two variables whose values i have extracted from the response body using JSON Extractor
[Here is the image showing two variables][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0RKx.png

In JSR223 PostProcessor, I have written below code which prints all the values in 1st column, but I want 2 separate columns variable wise.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
// Get total number of matches. (Returns string)
def resultCount = vars.get("AppObjectName_matchNr")
log.warn 'Output to jmeter console' +  resultCount
// Generate timestamp to create uniue file name.
String fileSuffix = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm").format(new Date())
// Create file Object
f = new File("results_Kr"+fileSuffix+".csv")
for (int i=1; i<=resultCount.toInteger(); i++)
{
  // Get each matching result one by one.
  records = vars.get("AppObjectName_" +i)
  Query = vars.get("QueryName_" + i)
// Write result to csv file.
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f,records + System.getProperty("line.separator"),true)
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f,Query + System.getProperty("line.separator"),true)
}
```

[Here is the image of code which creates .csv file & write both variables values in one column only][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVIeb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change first `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` function call to:

   ```
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f,records + ',' + Query + System.getProperty("line.separator"),true)
   ```
2. Remove second function call completely

Also be aware that in case of minimal concurrency when 2 or more threads will be writing data into the same file it might result into data corruption or loss so if this is the case - consider using either [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) or [convert the variables into JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) and write them in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group).

Comment: There is any command to overwrite existing data in csv file ?

Comment: You can either delete the file somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) or during first iteration of your for loop write the first line to the file without appending to existing by passing `false` to FileUtils.writeStringToFile()` function